# COUNT and GROUP BY SQL

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have an example data in the left table and the expected output is on the right side.

[image: View of example data and desired query output]

The requirement of output are:

- The COUNT counts the serial and Group by time and model.
- If there are more than 1 serial have the same value, choose the last one.

For example, at time 6, there are 3 model A with serial number 1,2,7, but we only count serial 7 because the first row (1-A-6) has a duplicate serial to the next row (1-A-7) so we don't count (1-A-6).

The question is, How can i make a SQL query to get data like output in only ONE query?

Comment: You are more likely to attract answers if you show your best attempt thus far. Please also add a Tag indicating the DB you are using.

Comment: You should read up on a GROUP BY with an aggregate (such as `COUNT`): http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php

Comment: By the sound of it you want `MAX()` not `COUNT()`

Comment: I can not get how to get that output. Can you elaborate for example why `6 a 1` and why `8 a 2`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad post. Jason W solved that for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique below uses `ROW_NUMBER` and subqueries to get the last instance of each serial, then the `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` to perform the aggregate. These should be supported by common DBMS's (since you didn't specify SQL Server or MySQL or whatever).

```
SELECT
    [Time],
    [Model],
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Time],
        [Model],
        [Serial],
        -- Paritioning by serial, get last instance of the serial
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY RowNum DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM (
        SELECT
            [Time],
            [Model],
            [Serial],
            -- Add a row number to help find the last value per requirements
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Serial]) AS RowNum
        FROM @T -- Your table here
        ) T
    ) T
WHERE RowNum = 1 -- Get last instance of the serial
GROUP BY
    [Time],
    [Model]
ORDER BY
    [Time]
```

Testing this with SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Serial] INT, [Model] CHAR(1), [Time] INT)
INSERT @T VALUES (1,'A', 6),(1, 'A', 7),(2,'A',6),(2,'A',7),
    (2,'A',9),(3,'A',8),(4,'A',8),(5,'B',9),(6,'B',9),(7,'A',6),
    (8,'B',10),(9,'B',8),(10,'B',8)
```

The desired output is achieved:

```
Time        Model Count
----------- ----- -----------
6           A     1
7           A     1
8           A     2
8           B     2
9           A     1
9           B     2
10          B     1
```